# ConnectionResetError with requests module raises exception inside of exception, crashing program

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, python-requests

The exception that crashes my program is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 397, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 479, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 447, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 491, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 531, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 496, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 415, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/CBB/scrape.py", line 301, in <module>
    main([2018, 11, 6, 2018, 12, 1])
  File "/Users/me/Documents/CBB/scrape.py", line 207, in main
    get_range(int(argv[0]), int(argv[1]), int(argv[2]), int(argv[3]), int(argv[4]), int(argv[5]))
  File "/Users/me/Documents/CBB/scrape.py", line 250, in get_range
    rg.get_bsc()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/CBB/scrape.py", line 103, in get_bsc
    self.get_pbp()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/CBB/scrape.py", line 120, in get_pbp
    soup = self.scraper.open_page(url=url)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/CBB/scrape_util.py", line 209, in open_page
    response = self.session.get(url, proxies={'https': ip, 'http': ip}, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I am running a webscraper from a location where the Internet will occasionally cut out for a second or two at a time, and in those cases I expect to receive some sort of exception. My approach to these exceptions is to wait a couple seconds and try again to reach the page. For most types of exceptions this issue causes, I am able to easily `except` the exception and retry. However, whenever this results in a `ConnectionResetError`, the program crashes because of exceptions raised inside exception handlers. I don't know how to fix this, because none of the code that raises any of the exceptions is written by me. I do not raise any exceptions, and I would like to stifle all of these so I can retry. Is there any way to ignore these exception-inside-of-exception crashes?

I am already excepting `ConnectionResetError`s and moving on from them as quickly as possible, which doesn't work. I am using the requests module to open these pages.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you expect, but have you tried catching the exception doing `except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:` ?

Comment: @IMCoins I'm trying this and it seems to be working so far. Fingers crossed that it holds with a larger sample. Thank you for the response!

Comment: did it work then ?

Comment: yes, this solution worked. thank you and thanks to the person who answered as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 different exceptions here that occur in the following order:

1. `ConnectionResetError`
2. `urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError`
3. `requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError`

The first two exceptions are excepted within the libraries that you are using and you shouldn't care about them. The last one (`requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError`) is not excepted and because you don't except it too, it is raised. So you should have:

```
except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
    # retry like you do for other exceptions
```

To illustrate what's happening, check this code:

```
def external_function():
    try:
        1 / 0    #  this produces ZeroDivisionError
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        a = b    #  this produces NameError

try:
    external_function()
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('This line is never printed')
except NameError:
    print('NamerError is caught')
```

`external_function()` illustrates `requests.get()`. Firstly, `ZeroDivisionError` error occurs. However, it is not raised, because it is handled by some external code. During handling of this exception, the external code produces another exception, this time `NameError`. This exception is not handled by the external code so it is returned to you. Then it is up to you to handle it. If you don't handle it, it is raised and it prints Traceback of all exceptions that occurred along the way even if they were excepted.